# Adjust size of centered div with fixed div at the left on pure CSS

Tags: html, css

How to automatically adjust size of the div which is horizontally centred, using another div which has `position: fixed` property?

To better understand what I mean please take a look at the picture below. Div `A` is a fixed div with a fixed size and div `B` is a div which is horizontally centred. I want div `B` to resize (when I resize browser window) in a such way so right border of `A` and left border of `B` never overlap (ideally, if the distance between the borders kept the same).

I know that this can be fairly easy done using JavaScript by reacting on resize events, but I'm wondering is there any way to achieve this in pure CSS?

[image]

Comment: can you share your html/css?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it, so I don't have any useful HTML. Basically, it's just two divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way.  This should work in older browsers too.

```html
<style>
div {
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 100px; }

#A {
 position: fixed;
 width: 150px; }

#B {
 margin: 0px 155px; }
</style>

<div id="A">Stuff</div>
<div id="B">Stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#a{
    width:200px;
}
#b{
    width:calc(100% - 400px);
}
```

Just set the width of B to be 100% of screen width minus twice the width of A and their borders will touch.

Answer (score 1):

When an element is given the settings `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` You can change the width of an element by using the `left` and `right` properties.

Simply add the same amount to the `right` as you would to the `left`

```css
#left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}
#middle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 165px;
    right: 165px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* For demo purposes */
html, body, div { height: 100%; margin: 0; } div { background: red; } #overflow { height: 200%; }
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="overflow"></div>
</div>
```